# Set Windows file version for a setup file created by Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I would like to ask if it is possible to set the "Version Number" that will be shown when I right-click the setup file in Windows and then select "Properties" and then "Details" (or "Version").

Currently it always shows "0.0.0.0" for my files.

Can anyone help?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you mean for the whole installer, or for one file installed by this installer?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It is the [`VersionInfoVersion`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_setup_versioninfoversion.htm) directive that you need to set. The reference describes this directive as:

> Specifies the binary file version value for the Setup version info.

Here is an example usage of this directive (but of course in real you will most certainly prefer to use some version information from your application instead of constant):

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program
VersionInfoVersion=1.2.3.4
```

Comment: Any reason for different `AppVersion` and `VersionInfoVersion`?

Comment: @sotn Yes. `AppVersion` is for the application that is being installed. `VersionInfoVersion` is for the installer itself.